# jQuery -- Prevent User from Scrolling Up Past Certain Scroll Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a one-page website.

Basically, I have this animated landing page with a landing image and a bootstrap `jumbotron`. I want to be able to implement a function where once the user scrolls past the end of the `jumbotron`, the user cannot scroll back up to view the landing image and the `jumbotron`. In a sense, either hide or delete the `<div>`s that were at the top, or completely disable scrolling back to those points.

I found this code, but it automatically disables scrolling up to the page top (after 200 px) on page load:

```
$(function() {
    var scrollPoint = 200;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint ? 
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint) : '';
  }).scroll();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of removing the scroll features, just make sure your parent container inside body is having max-height of 200px and overflow hidden. So anything below it will be not accessible for the user. If you disable the scroll then you need to also find scrollup event and enable it again which is lot to do

Comment: You can also call `event.preventDefault()` inside the scroll function once you have crossed `200px`

Comment: @harshit I tried this and it is not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to hide the jumbotron.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#id_of_jumbotron').offset().top + 
 $('#id_of_jumbotron').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
    hideTheJumboTron();
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    var scrollPoint = 200;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint) {
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint)
            return false;
        }
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: Yeah this actually works better than the method that I found, however there is the fundamental problem of not being able to scroll to the top of the page **on page load,** and that is a problem.

I want the user to be able to see the jumbotron and the elements above it when the page loads, but once those elements have been scrolled past, I want the user to not be able to scroll back up there.

Comment: You can add your condition(say `isAllLoaded`) after `$(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint` and everything will be OK @rehmanh